# New tag request: [stripe]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

I have just asked this question: [Stripe Cancel one payment in subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933658/stripe-cancel-one-payment-in-subscription)

I tried to tag it with [stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripe) however it's currently not an available tag and it suggested to ask in Meta about creating it.

Do we think this is a tag-worthy item? - the payment gateway [Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb) is getting quite big now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the (already existing) [stripe-payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripe-payments) tag for such questions; just `stripe` is too ambiguous.

The autocompletion should have suggested it for you.

However, just because the tag exists does *not* mean that *all* questions about Stripe are on-topic. You still need to have a specific *programming* problem here, while using their API for example. Also see [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: Ah - that's the correct answer, no I didn't see it suggested. However it is there now I have double checked. Will mark correct answer when it allows me.